# Special case of the Monodromy Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Let $D$ be the unit disc in the complex plane. Suppose the following theorem is true: If $f \in H(D)$ and
\begin{equation*}
f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n
\end{equation*} has radius of convergence $1$, then $f$ has at least one singular point on the unit circle. How can we apply this result to prove this version of the Monodromy Theorem: If $\Omega$ and $D$ are concentric discs, $(f,D)$ is a function element which can be analytically continued along every curve in $\Omega$ that starts at the origin $0$, then there exists a $g \in H(\Omega)$ such that $g(z)=f(z)$ on $D$?

Comment: *Hint:* $f$ can be developed into a power series at the common center of the disks. What happens if the radius of convergence is less than the radius of $\Omega$?

Comment: Taking a local continuation through any point of the unit circle shows no singular points anywhere on the circle, hence radius bigger; same applies if radius is less than the bigger radius of $\Omega$, so radius must be at least as big as that

Comment: @Martin R and @ Conrad, I got your points. Thanks!